# Glassfish 4.1 JMX: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint

Tags: glassfish

I've updated to Glassfish 4.1 from 4.0, and I can't access it from JConsole and VisualVM now (but I used to). JConsole outputs this before entering user/password:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:369)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:357)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:292)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:118)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:203)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1936)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1903)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:286)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:248)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:114)
    ... 9 more
```

I have this line in Glassfish's log:

```
JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal:8686/jndi/rmi://Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal:8686/jmxrmi
```

And I can connect using telnet. How can I solve this problem?